# Как добавить в простой слайдер текст

Tags: html, jquery, css

```js
$(function() {

  var index = 0
  // Все слайды.
    , slides = $('.mySlides');
        
  function carousel() {
    index++;
    if (index > slides.length - 1) {
      index = 0;
    }
    // Показать активный слайд за 1 сек.
    var active = slides.eq(index).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
    // Скрыть все слайды кроме активного за 1 сек.
    slides.not(active).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000);
  }

  // Запустить таймер.
  setInterval(carousel, 4000);
  
});
```

```css
.mySlides {
 position: relative;
 height: 562px;
 width: 100%;
}
.slide2 {
 margin-top: -587px;
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
    <img src="http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/siberian-husky-dog-breed-pictures/siberian-husky-dog-breed-pictures-3.jpg" class="mySlides slide1" >
    <img src="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/2690/large/siberian-husky-hereditary-health-and-longevity-55078254b0b96.jpg" class="mySlides slide2">
   </div>
```

Всем привет как видите тут у меня простой слайдер с рекурсией на jquery.Подскажите как для каждой фотографии написать надпись.Чтобы когда фотография менялось надпись менялось с ним синхронно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {

  var index = 0
  // Все слайды.
    , slides = $('.mySlides');
        
  function carousel() {
    index++;
    if (index > slides.length - 1) {
      index = 0;
    }
    // Показать активный слайд за 1 сек.
    var active = slides.eq(index).animate({ opacity: 1 }, 1000);
    // Скрыть все слайды кроме активного за 1 сек.
    slides.not(active).animate({ opacity: 0 }, 1000);
  }

  // Запустить таймер.
  setInterval(carousel, 4000);
  
});
```

```css
.mySlides {
 position: relative;
 height: 562px;
 width: 100%;
}
.slide2 {
 margin-top: -587px;
 opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slideshow">
    <div class="mySlides slide1"><img src="http://cdn1-www.dogtime.com/assets/uploads/gallery/siberian-husky-dog-breed-pictures/siberian-husky-dog-breed-pictures-3.jpg"></div>
    <div class="mySlides slide2"><img src="https://www.pets4homes.co.uk/images/articles/2690/large/siberian-husky-hereditary-health-and-longevity-55078254b0b96.jpg"><span>Текст</span></div>
   </div>
```

Т.е. добавить обертку каждой картинке и запихнуть в неё текст. А дальше стилизуйте надпись как хотите

Comment: понял спасибо большое